# three js mtl file basic material

Tags: three.js, wavefront

I need a basic material in my mesh.

I have this material in my MTL file:

```
newmtl window
Ns 0.000000
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.888930 0.994660 0.000000
Ks 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 1
```

what attribute makes material to be "THREE Basic Material"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given MTL file translates to

```
new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: new THREE.Color( 0.888930, 0.994660, 0 ) } );
```

Comment: for it to be a phong material you would need to specify the `specular` term, the `shininess` term, etc. I am not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: When i load *.obj mesh to scene, it uses a MTL library. Materials from MTL are loaded always as PhongMaterial. I need to create one of materials like BasicMaterial. I can only update MTL file, not hack js code.

Comment: if materials from MTL are always loaded as PhongMaterial there is nothing you can do in the .mtl file that will produce a BasicMaterial. But what you can do is after your object is loaded to go search for the specific PhongMaterial by name and change it to BasicMaterial.

Comment: I need a material looking like lighted window, (white surface not affected by light), is there another way to do this in mtl file without editing a js code?

Comment: I dont know if materials are always loaded as Phong, that was a meaning of question.

Comment: The OBJMTLLoader() always loads materials as MeshLambertMaterial().

Comment: please correct your answer, in your comment is it right, in answer not.

Comment: **Clarification**. The OBJLoader uses the **Phong** material, not the **Lambert** as stated. Please [take a look at the source code -latest version, not the one you might have in your js libraries-](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/6c7f000734f8579da37fb39e5c2e9e5e2dfb14f8/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js#L699)

Comment: Maybe someone just forgot to add normals to obj.